# Inverse Laplace Transformation

Tags: laplace-transform

I have a question about laplace transformation.

$\frac{8s+4}{s^2+23}$

I tried to split them. $\frac{8s}{s^2+23}$ is the image of a cosine and $\frac{4}{s^2+23}$ is the image of a sine.

Here is what I did :

$\frac{8s}{s^2+(\sqrt{23})^2}$  is the image of $8\cos(\sqrt{23}t)$   and $\frac{4}{s^2+(\sqrt{23})^2}$ is the image of $\frac4{\sqrt{23}}\sin(\sqrt{23}t)$

But according to homework, I am wrong. But I am sure I have the correct answer, there is no mistake.

Comment: If $$\frac{8s+4}{s^{2}+23}$$ is indeed the correct transform for your original problem then yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE ! Following the comment of @Mattos, your answer is indeed correct. When you ask a question, you must also give us all the informations that you have. Here for instance, you must write down what makes you believe what you have is wrong, precisely (what you homework says the answer should be).

Comment: @Tom-Tom my homework just says it is wrong. I checked syntax errors but there are no errors. Maybe my homework wants me to solve in another way. But I couldn't find another way to solve it...

Comment: Oh...I just checked it again and realised a small bracelet mistake. Now there is no problem. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind some Residue theory, we can check use that to check your solution.
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\biggl\{\frac{8s+4}{s^2+23}\biggr\}&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\frac{8s+4}{s^2+23}e^{st}ds\\
&=\sum\text{Res}
\end{align}
The poles in the $s$-plane occur at $s=\pm i\sqrt{23}$ both of order one. Then we have
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\biggl\{\frac{8s+4}{s^2+23}\biggr\}&= \lim_{s\to i\sqrt{23}}(s-i\sqrt{23})\frac{8s+4}{s^2+23}e^{st}+\lim_{s\to -i\sqrt{23}}(s+i\sqrt{23})\frac{8s+4}{s^2+23}e^{st}\\
&= \frac{8i\sqrt{23}+4}{2i\sqrt{23}}e^{it\sqrt{23}}+\frac{-8i\sqrt{23}+4}{-2i\sqrt{23}}e^{-it\sqrt{23}}\\
&=4e^{it\sqrt{23}}+4e^{-it\sqrt{23}}+\frac{2}{i\sqrt{23}}e^{it\sqrt{23}}-\frac{2}{i\sqrt{23}}e^{-it\sqrt{23}}\\
&=8\cos(t\sqrt{23})+\frac{4}{\sqrt{23}}\sin(t\sqrt{23})
\end{align}
Thus, the answer agrees with your by tables.